# Email body and Title is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-blade

In my case, I need to send mail when click the approve button. So email sending work was don but email content not send but I can't identify what are the issues,

This is my controller class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use \App\Mail\SendMail;

class MailSend extends Controller
{
    public function mailsend()
    {
        $details = [
            'title' => 'Title: Mail from xxxxxxx',
            'body' => 'Body: This is for testing email using smtp'
        ];

        \Mail::to('shasikamadushan555@gmail.com')->send(new SendMail($details));
        return view('emails.thanks');
    }
}
```

and then this is the my Mail class in mail folder

```
 <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $details;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Mail from Codex')
        ->view('emails.sendmail');    
    }
}
```

then show the my blade file according to mail content,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Company Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ $details['title'] }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $details['body'] }}</p>
    <p>Thank you</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In this sendmail.blade.php use to provide the mail content but in my case

```
<title>Conpany Name</title> 
<h1>{{ $details['title'] }}</h1>
<p>{{ $details['body'] }}</p>
```

above tags are not shown in the received mail but I need print above things in receiving mail
only show this tag

```
<p>Thank you</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be not setting the details in the constructor.

```
 <?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $details;

    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Mail from Codex')
        ->view('emails.sendmail');    
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shasika Madhushan no worries.

Comment: all the required things are correctly working after applying changes in _construct method according to your reply